# How To Post Custom Web Url link On Facebook?

Tags: javascript, facebook, magento-1.8, magento-1.9.1

I am passing the product image, url,summary,name on facebook using

```
    <a href="<?php echo 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&' . $_u; ?>" target="_blank" title="<?php echo $this->__('Share on Facebook') ?>" class="link-facebook">
        <?php echo $this->__('Share Facebook') ?>
    </a>.
```

It works fine. with this i want to push a custom link i.e "Click Here...". So how i can push the custom link on facebook

Answer (score 3):

Here I get Some Solution  regarding Custom Link sharing on facebook.

By using Sharer.php we can pass only four parameters.We can post custom link using feed.php as mention bellow.

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=Your_Appid&ref=site&display=popup&name=Name_come_here&caption=caption_come_here&description= description_you_want_to_share&actions=[{ name: "Name_of_custom_link", link: "custom_link_url" }]&redirect_uri=redirect_after_feed_on_facebook
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $this->__('Share Facebook') ?>
```

Replace that line with your custom information IE: "Click here..."

Comment: joe i pass parameter in $_u as per the facbook.com/sharer.php i.e   <?php $_u = 'p[url]=' . $_productUrl . '&p[images][0]=' . $_productImageUrl . '&p[title]=' . $_productName . '&p[summary]=' . urlencode(trim($_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description'))); ?>. here i want to pass a custom link i.e "click here". how i can pass it. It works fine for four parameter but failed for more then four paremeter